# asp net web api custom filter and http verb

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using a custom filter to validate the content type, like:

```
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext httpActionContext)
        {
            List<String> errors = new List<String>();

            // a
            if (httpActionContext.Request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json")
            {
            }
            else
            {
                errors.Add("Invalid content type.");
            }

                // more checks
        }
```

The above code is working fine, but the validation should check the request http verb, because it should validate the content type only for put or post. I don't want to remove the custom filter from httpget actions because I have more checks inside it, and I don't want to split the filter in two parts, meaning I have to check the http verb inside the filter, but I can't find how.

Any tips?

Comment: Why are you trying to restrict the media representation of the data? Out of the box both XML and JSON are supported, and the media handlers convert the representation to a strongly typed object for you. It would probably be better to have you API communicate the media types it accepts and then return a Bad Request error if necessary.

Comment: Because we will only support json (documentation, versioning, etc).

Comment: I guess that is up to you, but the ability to support multiple media types and letting the web API handle the format to object translation isn't something I would discard lightly.

Comment: @Oppositional only a quick comment to say you would probably return a 415 Unsupported Media Type not bad request.

Comment: @Mark Jones, you are correct that was what I intended to say ;-) Good catch!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the method type (post or put) from this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    string methodType = actionContext.Request.Method.Method;
    if (methodType.ToUpper().Equals("POST") 
            || methodType.ToUpper().Equals("PUT"))
    {
         // Your errors
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a commercial api, and we will only provide support and documentation for json. We will not support anything related to xml. It's a business requirement.

Comment: @user1330271 If you "will not support anything related to xml" then to fully remove XML you can remove the XML format in the config: void ConfigureApi(HttpConfiguration config) {     // Remove the XML formatter     config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter); }

Comment: #Facepalm  why didn't WebAPI ship with HttpVerbs that is available in MVC? I am glad they're merging the two in ASP.NET 5

Comment: @CuongLe how i can get posted values of action (in object not in querystring). in action filter.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get the HTTP Method of the request being validated by the filter, you can inspect the Method property of the request:

```
var method = actionContext.Request.Method;
```

I would recommend however that you break the filter apart, as you are quickly headed towards a big ball of mud scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using the standard HTTPVerb attributes above your controller methods:

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPut]
[HttpPost]
[HttpDelete]
[HttpPatch]
```

MVC Controllers for multiple:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get, HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

WebAPI Controlelrs for multiple

```
[AcceptVerbsAttribute("GET", "POST")]
```

Answer (score -1):

In the constructor of the action filter, you can pass in options/named parameters that will set the settings for the `OnActionExecuting` logic. Based on those settings you can switch up your logic.

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private HttpVerbs mOnVerbs;

    public MyActionFilterAttribute(HttpVerbs onVerbs)
    {
        mOnVerbs = onVerbs;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var currentVerb = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;

        if (mOnVerbs.HasFlag(HttpVerbs.Post)) { }
        else if (mOnVerbs.HasFlag(HttpVerbs.Get)) { }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

[MyActionFilter(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

Comment: You're answer is for MVC and not WebAPI